# I got Lysol in my headphone jack. How should I get it out?

Tags: iphone, headphones, damage

I was cleaning and I accidentally got Lysol in my phone. I’m mostly concerned about my headphone jack because I can’t listen to music since it’s saying I have headphones on when I don’t

Comment: Each generation of phone has different properties. Perhaps we could understand with an edit how many minutes ago you got liquid on the phone and which model it is? Also, precisely which Lysol branded product was used?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a piece of tissue and roll one corner into a tight long piece and slide it into the headphone jack and roll it around. This should clean out the jack. I'd recommend a cotton swab but I think the jack is too small. Maybe use a toothpick with the tissue paper. Be careful not to leave tissue in the headphone jack.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going under the assumption that you have the iPhone 6S or earlier as it was the *last* iPhone to ship with a headphone jack (this model is *not* water resistant).

When cleaning, you're not supposed to use any sort of household cleanser.  A soft, damp cloth is all that you need.  If, you must disinfect it (due to possible viral or bacterial contamination), *mild, soapy water* can be used to dampen the cloth and another can be used to rinse it.  If there's liquid dripping from the cloth or phone, it's way too much.

Apple has an excellent support document - [Cleaning your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207123) - that you should refer to.

> Avoid getting moisture in openings. **Don't use window cleaners,
>   household cleaners**, compressed air, aerosol sprays, solvents, ammonia,
>   abrasives, or cleaners containing hydrogen peroxide to clean your
>   iPhone. The front glass surfaces have an oleophobic coating.
>   <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

While it does say *not* to use compressed air, I would suggest using the "canned" air (from your local retail/office supply outlet) and ***gently*** blow air into the headphone jack.  Note that I said gently - don't pull the trigger "full blast" when doing this.   Your objective is to dry out whatever moisture may be in there.

That said, you should be prepared for the end result being that you shorted the connections in the headphone jack (residue from the Lysol) and it either needs to be cleaned professionally or replaced (the jack, not the whole phone).